# Windows 8 and Azure

Tags: html, azure, cloud, blob

I am trying to write a metro-style app where the users can upload files to the cloud, and view files uploaded by other users. I am writing this app in HTML5 / Javascript.

The problem is that even if what I would like to do is very simple (letting the users upload files in blob format to Azure), all the "tutorials" are very complicated.

This azure looks very cool, and I have a very cool idea for an app, but unfortunately there is no good documentation on how to use azure blob storage from a HTML W8 application.

Of course I would be very pleased if anyone could contradict me...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this - http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/?  It's probably a little dated since the updates to Release Preview, but it might give you some ideas.

I'm sure this will sound like an oversimplification, but Windows Azure blob storage has a REST API.  So if you can write REST - and in this case it'll be some XML/HTTPS - you're good to go.

Comment: Yes I tried this, and some days ago the link wasn't working, but now it is, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is sample code for interacting with Blob storage in Azure from an HTML5/JS app in Windows 8.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Blob-Sample-0e35889e)

Comment: In the case of this example, does the app have to be deployed to Azure (and how to do it), or will it reference a remote blob?

Comment: I mean, do I have to deploy the entire application to azure, even if I only need azure to store user's data? If it was the case, I think it wouldn't be possible, since I have Windows8 Release preview, and the following link only works for the previous version: http://watwindows8.codeplex.com

Comment: With blob storage you won't need to deploy the actual app to azure, but you do have to create an Azure account and set up a storage account within it.  Your Metro app won't be in Azure, but it will interact with Azure.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but what I don't understand is why in the link that you kindly supplied there is no reference to a remote storage, but only to an url of the kind "ms-appx-web://..." that means (I presume) a resource of the application. For example, in "PostMessageBlog.js" the image that I pick is stored in my machine, but I expected it to be stored in a remote blob.
Thank you very much for your answers